# Deploy Rails app on Passenger Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I´m trying to deploy a new rails app on pushion passenger integrate as Apache Mod and always get the following error:

```
Could not find byebug-4.0.5 in any of the sources.
```

If a comment in Gemfile.lock this dependency a get another error message for coffe-script. And no mather what dependency I comment I get:

```
Could not find **whatever** in any of the sources.
```

My environment is:

- ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]
- rails 4.2.1
- Passenger 5.0.7
- Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server built:   Mar 10 2015 13:05:59

For my app I just did...

```
rails new testapp
bundle install
```

And configure a new VirtualHost link to the public folder in testapp.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Are the gem versions in `Gemfile.lock` the same as the versions that are being installed when you run a `bundle install`?

Comment: Yeah, in the gem list appear 4.0.5 installed from de bundle install. Same than Gemfile.lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you really want to include byebug in production? Maybe only include it in the production group. Also make sure passenger is looking at the right path in order to find the gems as installed by bundler.

Comment: How I can look this path? Thanks!

Comment: the `gem env` command might help you see what is going on. Are you using rvm or rbenv?

Comment: I had another rubygems version for an older installation, restart all and works fine!! :)